# How can I call a class method on an instance within a different class __init__

Tags: python, oop, initialization

I am creating a tic-tac-toe game in python. I'm trying to call the update method from my Board class on my boardState object within the class **init** of my Turn class.
When I run it I get `NameError: name boardState is not defined`.

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self, player1 =  "player1", player2 = "player2"):
        self.p1 = player1
        self.p2 = player2
        self.matrix = MATRIX
        self.winner = 'none'
        self.available = getAvailable(self.matrix)
        
    def update(self):
        clear()
        getAvailable(self.matrix)
        self.show()

class Turn:
        def __init__(self, sym):
            self.sym = sym
            boardState.update()
            terminalState(boardState, self.sym, available)
            print(f"{self.sym}'s turn:")

def main():
    boardState = Board()
    altTurns()
```

Comment: You haven't created the object.  Do `boardState = Board()` to init a `Board` called `boardState`.  Then you can call `boardState.update()` to update that board.

Comment: (just edited to include my main function) Does it not work if I create the boars object before I create the turn object? I thought that since I  created it first within main() it should already exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting this error siense you haven't defined "boardState" before referencing it,

you need to set it to be a new Board Object before using it

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self, player1 =  "player1", player2 = "player2"):
        self.p1 = player1
        self.p2 = player2
        self.matrix = MATRIX
        self.winner = 'none'
        self.available = getAvailable(self.matrix)
        
    def update(self):
        clear()
        getAvailable(self.matrix)
        self.show()

class Turn:
        def __init__(self, sym):
            self.sym = sym
            boardState = Board() #the line I added
            boardState.update()
            terminalState(boardState, self.sym, available)
            print(f"{self.sym}'s turn:")
```

this should fix your problem

Comment: I thought creating it within main before calling the altturns function would mean it's already created

Comment: when you created 'boardState'  in the main function you created a variable that will be known only in the main function, but if you want to reference this variable inside 'Trun' class you need to initiate boardState inside the class (like my example)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `Turn` object to have access to the `boardState` object you've created in `main()` (and for `main` in turn to have access to the updated `boardState`), you should pass it in as a parameter to give all of the relevant functions access to it.

I assume the `Turn` is created by `altTurns`, so `altTurns` should itself take a board object that it can use to create the initial `Turn`.

```
class Turn:
        def __init__(self, sym, boardState):
            self.sym = sym
            boardState.update()
            terminalState(boardState, self.sym, available)
            print(f"{self.sym}'s turn:")

def altTurns(boardState):
    sym = None  # or something?
    turn = Turn(sym, boardState)
    # more turns happen?

def main():
    boardState = Board()
    altTurns(boardState)
    # our boardState has now been updated by Turn()
```